# Django can't download file via admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm using Django version 1.10.5 to build a website with the following apps installed:

- django.contrib.admin
- django.contrib.auth
- django.contrib.contenttypes
- django.contrib.sessions
- django.contrib.messages
- django.contrib.staticfiles
- bootstrap3
- myapp
- storages

In the models.py I defined the following class:

```
class SourceData(models.Model):
    File = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='Upload')
```

On the website I tried to upload a file via admin, which was successfull. However if I click on the uploaded file, I get a Page not found 404 Error.

Any help or ideas apreciated.
Thanks in advance!

#### Update 12:45 CET

settings.py

```
"""
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.5.
"""

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = ''
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'myapp',
    'storages',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin'
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'DE-de'
TIME_ZONE = 'CET'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py:

```
"""myapp URL Configuration
"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    url(r'^helloworld/', views.helloworld, name='Hello World!'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout')
]
```

Comment: Have you configured your media URL ?

Comment: I'm using the default media route, why does the default media URL not work?

Comment: Can you share your settings.py and urls.py file

Comment: I added the requested files.

Comment: You need to add MEDIA_URL='/media/'

Comment: I added the line in the settings.py, unfortunately I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to add this lines into the urls.py file (importing the needed libraries)

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)
```

Full explanation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this might work. How would you implement this in a productive environment?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#deployment
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/
First, read the docs and if have any questions open a new thread ;)

Comment: Yes, I just read your linked site and followed the instructions there. It worked fine, even without debug. Thanks!